# Why is it showing a bug on line 50 in MimeMessage

Tags: java

1. Whenever i try to compile this servlet it keeps on showing a bug on
   line 50:

```
    package com.registration;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    @WebServlet("/Process")
    public class Process extends HttpServlet {

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();

            final String from = "//use ur own";
            final String pass = "//use ur own";

            final MimeMessage message;

            String first_name = request.getParameter("first_name");
            String last_name = request.getParameter("last_name");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");

            httpSession.setAttribute("first_name", first_name);
            httpSession.setAttribute("last_name", last_name);
            httpSession.setAttribute("email", email);
            httpSession.setAttribute("password", password);

            int randomPin = (int) (Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 6));

            httpSession.setAttribute("randomPin", randomPin);

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); // THIS IS THE SMTP SERVER SERVER ADDRESS
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // THIS IS THE PORT FOR THE SMTP SERVER

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass); // THIS IS TO AUTHENTICATE YOUR GEMAIL ACCOUNT
                }
            });

            try {
                message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("jskm.shop.co@gmail.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email));
                message.setSubject("Your otp for registeration is"); // SETS THE SUBJECT FOR THE EMAIL
                message.setContent(
                        "<h:body style=background-color:white;font-family:verdana; color:0000ee "
                                + "Enter this OTP for your successfull registeration</br></br>" + "</body>",
                        "text/html; charset-utf-8");
                Transport.send(message);
                System.out.println("Email was sent successfully");

                response.sendRedirect("../otp.jsp");

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: What bug it is showing?

Comment: Remove `final` from non final variable

Answer (score 0):

Remove final from a *non final* variable `message`:

```
MimeMessage message;
```

Comment: and on the console its showing -- INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using message.setText instead of message.setContent